# Error running beta iOS app on device

Tags: ios, beta-testing

To the best of my knowledge I've followed [Apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) for distributing a beta app to users. The app installs on the test device but (1) there is only the default icon and (2) when I try to run the app the name changes back from the app name to "Installing...". Synching with iTunes re-installs the app and starts the process over again.

On my test devices the icon shows up and everything runs fine.

Any hints to what might be causing this, or how I can get an error logs from the test machine?

Note that using testflight is not an option for me right now.

(I beta tested some apps a few years ago without problems under the old system where you distributed a certificate to the users, but I haven't used this new system before.)

Comment: @AaronBrager See my answer below -- it seems that there was some sort of misconfiguration in the certificates. Cleaning them up fixed it. If you want to write up an answer I'll gladly accept it instead of mine below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell, because there are lots of steps. My guess is that you missed one of these three: "The app successfully launches if the app’s bundle ID matches the App ID, the signature matches the distribution certificate, and the device is in the device list of the ad hoc provisioning profile."

Answer (score 1):

It seems that @AaronBrager had the right idea. First I cleaned up all of my certificates and profiles (there was a lot of built up cruft and some had similar names). Then I re-built the app, archived it, etc. Xcode like didn't something about my certificates, but handled the problem automatically. Then my app was both able to install and run without problem on the beta test device.